# Surface area of $x^{2/3}$ + $y^{2/3}$ = 4 from $0 \le y \le 8$ revolved around $y$-axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

I am aware that the general formula to calculate surface area of revolution is:
$$2\pi\int_a^b x \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dy $$

Here, we can rearrange the equation so it becomes:
$x = (4-y)^{2/3}y^{3/2}$

so,
$\frac{dx}{dy} = −^{−1/3}(4−^{2/3})^{1/2}$

and
$\frac{dx}{dy}^2 = −^{−2/3}(4−^{2/3})$

Assuming I've done everything correct, my integral should look like:

$2\pi\int_a^b (4−^{2/3})^{3/2}y^{-2/3}$

Have I done everything correct so far? What does my final integral evaluate into?

Comment: Your formula for $x$ is wrong. It should be $$x=\left(4-y^{2/3}\right )^{3/2}$$

Comment: Work with $y=\left(4-x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}$ to end with a very simple integrand